# android, calling a service from different app

Tags: android, android-service

I am making an Android app and I need to call a customized service from another app. The service is already running when I call it (I cannot start it from the other app). I could call it and it actually runs but my problems come when I want to get the results. I use a "LocalBroadcastManager" in the service and a "BroadcastReceiver" in the other app.

APP:

```
//onStart

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("xx.yy.zz.myservice.action"); 

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);



//Button listener:

Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("xx.yy.zz.","xx.yy.zz.myservice")); 

intent.putExtra(...    
startService(intent);
```

Service:

```
//onCreate

mLocalBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);



//onStartCommand

Intent intentR = new Intent("action");

 intentR.putExtra(.... 

mLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intentR);
```

Any ideas?? I am working with Android 26.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I use a LocalBroadcast so the message was just sent inside the 
 service application, using the normal Broadcast fixes the problem.